# Test Driven Development with Django

Tags: python, unit-testing, django

I'm learning TDD with Django and currently I'm testing my `CreateView` class. I feel like I'm not using best practices but am not sure on how to improve my code.

test_reservation_create.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from reservations.models import Reservation
from src.factories import UserFactory, GroupFactory, ProfileFactory, TagFactory


class TestCreateReservation(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        persona = UserFactory(groups=(GroupFactory.create(),))

        ProfileFactory(user=persona, )
        persona.profile.tags.add(TagFactory())

    def test_create_view_denies_anonymous(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('reservation-create'), follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/login?next=/r/create/')

    def test_loads_template_for_user(self):
        self.client.login(username='john', password='defaultpassword')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('reservation-create'))
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_create_blank_for_user(self):
        self.client.login(username='john', password='defaultpassword')
        data = {
            'stops-TOTAL_FORMS': u'2',
            'stops-INITIAL_FORMS': u'0',
            'stops-MIN_NUM_FORMS': u'0',
            'stops-MAX_NUM_FORMS': u'1000',
            'stops-0-id': u'',
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('reservation-create'), data=data)
        self.assertFormError(response,'form','passenger_name','This field is required.')
        self.assertFormError(response,'form','passenger_lastname','This field is required.')
        self.assertFormError(response,'form','service_date','This field is required.')
        self.assertFormError(response,'form','author_alias','This field is required.')

    def test_formset_validation(self):
        self.client.login(username='john', password='defaultpassword')
        data = {
            'stops-TOTAL_FORMS': u'2',
            'stops-INITIAL_FORMS': u'0',
            'stops-MIN_NUM_FORMS': u'0',
            'stops-MAX_NUM_FORMS': u'1000',
            'stops-0-id': u'',
            'service_date':'02/07/2027',
            'passenger_name':'John',
            'passenger_lastname':'Doe',
            'service_type':'BUSINESS',
            'status':0,
            'payment_options':'CASH',
            'amount':'0.00',
            'author_alias':'Faker',
            'vehicle':'CAR',
            'pax_number':1
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('reservation-create'), data=data, follow=True)
        self.assertContains(response,'You must have specify both place1 and place2')

    def test_create_minimal_for_user(self):
        self.client.login(username='john', password='defaultpassword')
        data = {
            'stops-TOTAL_FORMS': u'2',
            'stops-INITIAL_FORMS': u'0',
            'stops-MIN_NUM_FORMS': u'0',
            'stops-MAX_NUM_FORMS': u'1000',
            'stops-0-id': u'',
            'service_date':'02/07/2027',
            'passenger_name':'John',
            'passenger_lastname':'Doe',
            'stops-0-time': '11:00',
            'stops-0-place':'Place1',
            'stops-1-place': 'Place2',
            'service_type':'BUSINESS',
            'status':0,
            'payment_options':'CASH',
            'amount':'0.00',
            'author_alias':'Faker',
            'vehicle':'CAR',
            'pax_number':1
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('reservation-create'), data=data, follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('dashboard'))

        reservation = Reservation.objects.first()
        self.assertEquals(reservation.service_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),'2027-02-07')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.passenger_name,'John')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.passenger_lastname,'Doe')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.service_type,'BUSINESS')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.status,0)
        self.assertEquals(reservation.author_alias,'Faker')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.payment_options,'CASH')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.amount,0.00)
        self.assertEquals(reservation.vehicle,'CAR')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.pax_number,1)

        self.assertEquals(reservation.stops.first().place, 'Place1')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.stops.last().place, 'Place2')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.stops.first().time.strftime('%H:%M'), '11:00')

    def test_create_minimal_for_user_and_new(self):
        self.client.login(username='john', password='defaultpassword')
        data = {
            'stops-TOTAL_FORMS': u'2',
            'stops-INITIAL_FORMS': u'0',
            'stops-MIN_NUM_FORMS': u'0',
            'stops-MAX_NUM_FORMS': u'1000',
            'stops-0-id': u'',
            'service_date':'02/07/2027',
            'passenger_name':'John',
            'passenger_lastname':'Doe',
            'stops-0-time': '11:00',
            'stops-0-place':'Place1',
            'stops-1-place': 'Place2',
            'service_type':'BUSINESS',
            'status':0,
            'payment_options':'CASH',
            'save_and_new':'Submit',
            'amount':'0.00',
            'author_alias':'Faker',
            'vehicle':'CAR',
            'pax_number':1
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('reservation-create'), data=data, follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('reservation-create'))

        reservation = Reservation.objects.first()
        self.assertEquals(reservation.service_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),'2027-02-07')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.passenger_name,'John')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.passenger_lastname,'Doe')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.service_type,'BUSINESS')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.status,0)
        self.assertEquals(reservation.author_alias,'Faker')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.payment_options,'CASH')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.amount,0.00)
        self.assertEquals(reservation.vehicle,'CAR')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.pax_number,1)

        self.assertEquals(reservation.stops.first().place, 'Place1')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.stops.last().place, 'Place2')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.stops.first().time.strftime('%H:%M'), '11:00')

    def test_create_minimal_for_user_and_clone(self):
        self.client.login(username='john', password='defaultpassword')
        data = {
            'stops-TOTAL_FORMS': u'2',
            'stops-INITIAL_FORMS': u'0',
            'stops-MIN_NUM_FORMS': u'0',
            'stops-MAX_NUM_FORMS': u'1000',
            'stops-0-id': u'',
            'service_date':'02/07/2027',
            'passenger_name':'John',
            'passenger_lastname':'Doe',
            'stops-0-time': '11:00',
            'stops-0-place':'Place1',
            'stops-1-place': 'Place2',
            'service_type':'BUSINESS',
            'status':0,
            'payment_options':'CASH',
            'save_and_clone':'Submit',
            'amount':'0.00',
            'author_alias':'Faker',
            'vehicle':'CAR',
            'pax_number':1
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('reservation-create'), data=data, follow=True)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, 'John')

        reservation = Reservation.objects.first()
        self.assertEquals(reservation.service_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),'2027-02-07')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.passenger_name,'John')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.passenger_lastname,'Doe')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.service_type,'BUSINESS')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.status,0)
        self.assertEquals(reservation.author_alias,'Faker')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.payment_options,'CASH')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.amount,0.00)
        self.assertEquals(reservation.vehicle,'CAR')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.pax_number,1)

        self.assertEquals(reservation.stops.first().place, 'Place1')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.stops.last().place, 'Place2')
        self.assertEquals(reservation.stops.first().time.strftime('%H:%M'), '11:00')

    def test_invalid_date_in_past(self):
        self.client.login(username='john', password='defaultpassword')
        data = {
            'stops-TOTAL_FORMS': u'2',
            'stops-INITIAL_FORMS': u'0',
            'stops-MIN_NUM_FORMS': u'0',
            'stops-MAX_NUM_FORMS': u'1000',
            'stops-0-id': u'',
            'service_date': '02/07/2010',
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('reservation-create'), data=data)
        self.assertFormError(response, 'form', 'service_date', 'Date can\'t be in the past!')
```

Answer (score 4):

The code has a lot of repetitive blocks, a test flow is mixed up with the data and the logic making it difficult to follow, the number of different assertions makes the tests bigger and more complicated.

I think you should have a much more readable code if you would switch to "data-driven tests" with "parameterized tests" (e.g. [there is a built-in support in `pytest`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html)) or take a look at the [`ddt` package](https://github.com/txels/ddt).

Also, instead of checking multiple model fields with multiple asserts, try [dumping the model to, for example, a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925671/convert-django-model-object-to-dict-with-all-of-the-fields-intact) and compare it with a desired dictionary - basically this way you would check all the fields at once. Of course, in this case, in case of a failure, the output would be less clear, but if you have a good test runner like `nose` or `pytest`, this should not be a problem for the number of fields we are talking about.

Other notes:

- the user credentials should probably be moved to a single place - to a config file for your tests. This way, if they change, we would need to change it in a single place instead of looking for them in multiple places in the code.
- think about splitting your test case into multiple test cases - e.g. one for access control, the other for validation tests etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions for how you can improve your tests to better guard against possible issues as well as make them more maintainable.

- Always call `super().setUp()` if you override `setUp` in your tests.

  This may not seem like something which is required, but sometimes you'll use a custom test class which has some custom logic in the `setUp` method (usually involving the database). It's caught me a few times and I've ended up having to remove a bunch of test objects from my database.
- If you aren't going to hard-code your test urls, don't hard code where you expect them to redirect to.

  `test_create_view_denies_anonymous` tests that unauthenticated users will get redirected, but you're hard-coding the url that it should be redirected to. You can safely rely on Django's `reverse` not messing up, which will allow you to build out the url it's redirected to while still handling you renaming the url in the future.
- Don't hard-code your username and password in your test factory.

  This was mentioned already, but you should instead be setting the password for the user within the `setUp` for your test class, or at the start of the test itself. This allows you to create multiple users with different names, all within the same test.
- Always assert your assumptions

  In `test_create_minimal_for_user` you are asserting that the user is redirected to the dashboard, which I'm assuming should mean the reservation was created. And then you call `Reservation.objects.first()`, which will either give you a `Reservation` or will give you `None` without raising an error. You then continue on, assuming that the reservation was returned, to test the properties of the reservation.

  You should instead be asserting that a `Reservation` exists before you try to retrieve it. Also, you can use `.get()` on any manager as long as there is a single object, which you appear to be assuming.

  ```
  self.assertEqual(Reservation.objects.count(), 1)

  reservation = Reservation.objects.get()
  ```

  This will ensure that you will either get a `Reservation` back, or your test will fail (not error out) because there were no reservations created. This also handles the case where multiple reservations were created for some reason.
- Avoid hard-coding dates in your tests

  You managed to pick dates that were far into the future, but usually people forget to do that. In my experience, we had a bunch of tests which were hard-coded to fail in 2 years and 2 months, and we never touched those tests to update the dates until everything started failing on May 1st, 2015.

  You can avoid hard-coding dates in your tests by generating relative dates in the future using the `timedelta` module.

  ```
  from datetime import datetime, timedelta

  current_date = datetime.now()
  one_week_into_the_future = current_date + timedelta(weeks=1)

  formatted_date = one_week_into_the_future.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
  ```